# Using a File Watcher in Webstorm to update a text file

Tags: macos, bash, webstorm

In Webstorm 8, how do I set up a [file watcher](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/new-watcher-dialog.html) to update a text file with the current date and time?  I started to investigate using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to update the text file.

I'd like to overwrite line 2 of a text file with the output of `date`, prefixed with #:

```
# Wed May 28 08:31:01 CDT 2014
```

I've got this far in OSX bash.  I can't get it to work in Webstorm yet.

```
sed -e "2s|.*|# `date`|g" "cache.manifest" > "cache.manifest.tmp" && mv cache.manifest.tmp cache.manifest
```

This writes the output of `date` into line 2 of a temp file, then renames the temp file back to cache.manifest.

How in the world do I get this to run in Webstorm's file watcher?  The cache.manifest file is in my project directory then /app and won't move.

In the Edit Watcher dialog I have this so far but the darn thing just outputs the whole cache.manifest file to the Webstorm terminal (including the edited second line as # `date`). Then "process finished with exit code 1". Very helpful.  :)

```
File Type: Any
Scope: Open Files
Program: sed
Arguments: -e "2s|.*|# `date`|g" "cache.manifest" > "cache.manifest.tmp" && mv cache.manifest.tmp cache.manifest
Working Directory: $ProjectFileDir$/app
```

Comment: example input and output would make it a cleaner question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute bash script as a file watcher program.

/home/segrey/my_scripts/timestamp-updater.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e "2s|.*|# `date`|g" "cache.manifest" > "cache.manifest.tmp" && mv cache.manifest.tmp cache.manifest
```

Then specify path to this script in `Program` field and leave `Arguments` field empty:

[image: Custom File Watcher]

Once any file is saved in a project, the second line of `app/cache.manifest` will be updated.

Comment: I'm getting error 13 permission denied when I try running my .sh file this way.  I can run it fine from the terminal window. Are there any examples with screenshots of setting this up?

Comment: I've updated my answer (screenshot attached).
About error 13 permission denied: try to run the same command from the embedded Terminal (see Terminal tool window at the bottom: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html).